# Integer solutions for Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory

Find all pairs $(p, n)$ of positive integers where $p$ is a prime number and  $p^3 − p = n^7 − n^3$.

*Attempt at question*:

I have factorised both the sides of the equation
$(p-1)(p)(p+1)=(n-1)(n+1)(n^3)(n^2+1)$ and tried equating terms under different cases.

I am not sure if I am procedding in the right way or in the shortest way possible?

Comment: If you want the full solution, see this question I gave as duplicate. However, I think it would be better if you try to find the solution yourself with my hint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint:** A slightly more clear factorisation might be $p(p-1)(p+1) = n^3(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$.

Now, since $p$ is prime, $p$ is a divisior of one of the factors on the right hand side.

Therefore $p \mid n$, $p \mid n-1$, $p \mid n+1$ or $p \mid n^2+1$. You can break this up in cases.

For each case, you will discover that the right hand side is quickly too large to be a solution.